# Create a macro to filter between two dates vba

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I am trying to write a macro that will filer  between two dates but I don't know how to do it.All my dates are in column D.I'd tried to filter using this code but the filter doesn't work how it's supposed to work.

```
Sheets("All").ListObjects("Table_Name").Range.AutoFilter Field:=4, _
    Criteria1:=DTPicker1, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:=txtEDate
    Sheets("All").Select
```

Comment: What are `DTPicker` and `txtEDate`?  When you have a date column the value you see might be, for example, 3/3/15 or 3Mar15 or 2015-03-03. But these are just display formats.  Behind the scenes Excel holds dates as the number of days since 1/1/1900.  For example 3Mar15 is 42066.  Try filtering on appropriate numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you have entered the code it will filter for two EXACT dates. If you are looking for a time range then you need to expand upon your code by including comparative signs such as < and >:

```
Sheets("All").ListObjects("Table_Name").Range.AutoFilter Field:=4, _
    Criteria1:=">=" & DateSerial(Year(DTPicker1), Month(DTPicker1), Day(DTPicker1)), Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<="DateSerial(Year(txtEDate), Month(txtEDate), Day(txtEDate))
```

Furthermore, I always like to use DateSerial in VBA in order to ensure that a date is recognized and entered as such. It also eliminates possible problems if you are dealing with different international date formats.

You also might want to remove any prior filters:

```
Sheets("All").ShowAllData
```

Otherwise, your code will just add to existing filters.